# How do you assign a static IP to a GKE Ingress?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, static-ip-address, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

I have a GKE cluster setup where I have a service running as an internal load balancer and an ingress for this service. Is there a way to set a static IP to the ingress controller? My reference guide is here:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with one annotation in the ingress definition. You can view more in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2b_using_an_ingress)